# How to add new lines into a variable passed into pug

Tags: node.js, html, express, pug, pug-loader

I am trying to pass values that need to include new lines/brake lines into pug files.

So far I have tried

```
var value1 = "value 1";
var value2 = "value 2";
var infromation = "\n" + value1 + "\n" + value2;
res.render('pugfile', { information: information });
```

but when this is rendered in pug through

```
p Your messages are: #{information}
```

The html is rendered as

```
<p> 
value 1
value 2
</p>
```

but the new line is not shown on the displayed webpage, which is the problem.
Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of putting `\n` for newline, use `<br>` for break. And also you need to escape the string. For reference [check this](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped).

Try this.

```
  let value1 = "value 1";
  let value2 = "value 2";
  // let information = "\n" + value1 + "\n" + value2;
  let information = "<br>" + value1 + "<br>" + value2;
  res.render("index", { information: information });
```

And in pug template

```
p Your messages are: !{information}
```

[Please check here for working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/00r28k32xl)

Comment: Ill give it a try and get back to you

Comment: Ok. Please let me know whether it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but if you are using data from users then it's very dangerous to use un-escaped values like `!{information}`, it's safer to split the string by the newlines and use standard escaped strings:

```
p Your messages are:
  each str, indx in String(information).split('\n')
    if indx > 0
      br
    | #{str}
```